# Fifties/Sixties novel with four (maybe) boys born with big eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel

While visiting a friend of my wife who is going into a nursing home she mentioned the novel as something belonging to her mother that featured possibly four boys who were born with big eyes that were searching for each other.  That is all that she remembered.  What prompted this was my mentioning of Wyndham's Midwich Cuckoos so I pretty sure that was not it.  If anybody has any ideas as to what that book might have been, I (and she) would appreciate.  It would be hard for me to accept any answer unless it was so spot on as to exclude any other answer.

Comment: They wouldn't be silver eyes, would they?

Comment: In _The Midwich Cuckoos_ the children have eyes with irises that are gold, but their eyes are normal in all other respects including size.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance some details were misremembered, *[The Girl with the Silver Eyes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1442421703)* by Willo Davis Roberts is a partial match.

> Katie Welker is used to being alone. She would rather read a book than deal with other people. Other people don’t have silver eyes. Other people can’t make things happen just by thinking about them!
>
> But these special powers make Katie unusual, and it’s hard to make friends when you’re unusual. Katie knows that she’s different but she’s never done anything to hurt anyone so why is everyone afraid of her? Maybe there are other kids out there who have the same silver eyes…and the same talents…and maybe they’ll be willing to help her.

Katie is one of at least four children who, as a result of their mothers taking a drug (I think it was for headaches) at a company they worked for during their pregnancies, have mental powers. Katie can levitate things. One of the boys can talk to his pets. All of them can mentally communicate with each other once they meet. I believe that Katie's eyes are described as "enormous behind her glasses", but I think that's more a matter of the glasses themselves, with the actual primary physical trait being the silver eyes. Also, it's three girls and a boy, as I recall it, rather than four boys. Lastly, it was published in 1980, which would probably make it too recent for this friend's mother to have read it in their youth, although they definitely could have picked it up later.

Comment: Pretty sure that the timeframe alone torpedoes that one.  thanks for trying, though.